# 6 weeks Moving Average Over Same Day of week

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, rows, between, moving-average

I am calculating the 6 weeks moving average, for the same days of the week, for the volume of calls in a call center.

What I mean by this is the same 6 previous days (last 6 tuesdays, last 6 wednesdays, etc.)

I've got the following code working, but not flexible at all:

```
SELECT
    [ROW_DATE],
    [DEPARTMENT_DESC],
    [totalcalls],
    AVG([TOTALCALLS]) OVER(ORDER BY [DEPARTMENT_DESC],
                                    [ROW_DATE] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [MOVING_AVG]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        [ROW_DATE] AS [ROW_DATE],
        [DEPARTMENT_DESC] AS [DEPARTMENT_DESC],
        SUM([CALLS_OFFERED_ACTUALS]) AS [TOTALCALLS]
    FROM [GEMDB].[dbo].[V_PRD_ACT_HSPLIT_intradayLCWcallsTable]
    WHERE ROW_DATE IN(CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 42), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 7), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 14), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 21), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 28), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 35))
    AND [DEPARTMENT_DESC] = 'techops'
    GROUP BY
        ROW_DATE,
        [DEPARTMENT_DESC]
) AS tbl
ORDER BY
    ROW_DATE,
    [DEPARTMENT_DESC];
```

The output looks like this:
[Moving Average for August 23rd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol3Bw.jpg)

The issue with the above code is it gives me the value for 1 day of the week (August 23rd).
I would like to get the 6 weeks moving average for the last 7 days, without writing GETDATE 49 times, which would be crazy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show like in a mock Excel sheet or something what the expected output would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to create a simplified example of what you are asking if I've understood it correctly. This uses 2 weeks worth of data but should work for larger datasets. You can run this code in isolation to test and adapt if it fits your requirement:

```
CREATE TABLE #calls
(
    TotalCalls INT,
    CallDate DATE
);

-- 2 weeks worth of calls
INSERT INTO #calls
(
    TotalCalls,
    CallDate
)
VALUES
(12, '20170801'), -- starts on a Tuesday
(13, '20170802'),
(17, '20170803'),
(20, '20170804'),
(4, '20170805'),
(8, '20170806'),
(10, '20170807'),
(14, '20170808'),
(18, '20170809'),
(16, '20170810'),
(7, '20170811'),
(11, '20170812'),
(19, '20170813'),
(14, '20170814');

-- casts to numeric with decimal places for the average for accuracy
-- DayName - gives the day names for grouping
-- DayNo - gives you the day number for ordering
-- Instances - gives you how many days were included in the average
-- WHERE - filters to dates >= date - 42 for 6 weeks
SELECT AVG(CAST(c.TotalCalls AS NUMERIC(5,2))) AvgCalls,
       DATENAME(dw,c.CallDate ) DayName,
       DATEPART(dw, c.CallDate) DayNo,
       COUNT(c.CallDate) Instances
FROM #calls AS c
WHERE c.CallDate > GETDATE() - 42
GROUP BY DATENAME(dw, c.CallDate ), DATEPART(dw, c.CallDate)
ORDER BY DATEPART(dw, c.CallDate)
```

**Produces:**

```
AvgCalls    DayName    DayNo    Instances
13.500000   Sunday     1        2
12.000000   Monday     2        2
13.000000   Tuesday    3        2
15.500000   Wednesday  4        2
16.500000   Thursday   5        2
13.500000   Friday     6        2
7.500000    Saturday   7        2
```

Comment: What a simple and smooth solution. This works flawlessly. Thank you Tanner!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option...

```
WITH
    cte_SixWeekCal AS (
        SELECT 
            c.WEEK_NO,
            ROW_DATE_BEG = DATEADD(WEEK, -13 + c.WEEK_NO, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)),
            ROW_DATE_END = DATEADD(WEEK, -7 + c.WEEK_NO, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
        FROM 
            ( VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6) ) c (WEEK_NO)
        )
SELECT 
    swc.WEEK_NO,
    ROW_DATE = ROW_DATE_END,
    ahid.DEPARTMENT_DESC.
    ahid.MOVING_AVG
FROM 
    cte_SixWeekCal swc
    CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT 
                    ahi.DEPARTMENT_DESC,
                    MOVING_AVG = AVG(ahi.CALLS_OFFERED_ACTUALS)
                FROM 
                    [GEMDB].dbo.V_PRD_ACT_HSPLIT_intradayLCWcallsTable ahi
                WHERE 
                    ih.InvoiceDate >= swc.ROW_DATE_BEG
                    AND ih.InvoiceDate <= swc.ROW_DATE_END
                GROUP BY
                    ahi.DEPARTMENT_DESC
                ) ahid;
```